# The php return page does not show error message when error is occured

Tags: php, apache

I have already installed Apache2.4 and PHP7.2.2

I debugged some php page, they had error, and the return page have displayed error messages

Then I edited the httpd.conf, changed the lines

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs"
<Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "D:\mywebs"
    <Directory "D:\mywebs">
```

then when a page has error, it only displayed the content from the begin of the page to the line has error but it does not show error message

I had change the path back to "C:\Apache24\htdocs" but there still have been the problem

Can anyone help

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying you have to configure you PHP not apache server
You can use some php inbuilt function to show error or change the configuration file

**Using PHP**

You have add below code in root of the PHP file

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

**Using php.ini file**

Find php.ini file in your PHP installation and open it, Search `display_errors`
variable and set value `On`

```
display_errors=On
```

And then restart server

Comment: I have tried the two way you recommended but it had no effect. Thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks, it worked. At the first time when I changed ini.php to display_errors=On, errors was not displayed. But when I changed it to off and add the above code to the root(the way using php), they were displayed. Then I commented the php code and changed display_errors=On, the messages were still showed.